# AES-GCM ciphertext that deciphers under two keys

Tags: aes, authenticated-encryption, gcm

How can we exhibit an [AES-GCM](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf#page=23) ciphertext, including IV and 128-bit authentication tag, and distinct keys $K_0$ and $K_1$, so that decryption succeeds for both keys?

What degree of control do we have on the respective plaintexts obtained by such decryption? Can that extend to the point that [this nightmare](https://soatok.blog/robustness/) ([referring page](https://soatok.blog/2020/09/09/designing-new-cryptography-for-non-standard-threat-models/)) of the same encrypted and authenticated ciphertext decrypting to two meaningful but wildly different documents holds (for some standard document/archive format)?

Numerical example (or link to that) welcome!

---

Update: I'm [told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55768114#55768114) this is as described [there](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/016.pdf#page=10) by Yevgeniy Dodis, Paul Grubbs, Thomas Ristenpart and Joanne Woodage's [*Fast Message Franking: From Invisible Salamanders to Encryptment*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/016), in [proceedings of Crypto 2018](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-96884-1_6); but I'd like an independent answer focusing on the how (even if that's not detailed), and leaving out Associated Data if that's not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we exhibit an [AES-GCM][1] ciphertext, including IV and 128-bit authentication tag, and distinct keys $K_0$ and $K_1$, so that decryption succeeds for both keys?

It's quite easy (if you grok linear algebra in $GF(2^{128})$

Here's what you do:

- You arbitrarily select the keys $K_0$ and $K_1$,  the nonce and the ciphertext/AAD (except for one block, which can be anywhere, including in the AAD); we'll assume that the one block is at indes $i$ (where the last block of the ciphertext is index 2, the next to last is index 3, and so on - this rather odd convention is related to how GCM works internally).

We then compute the GCM authentication key $H_0 = AES_{K_0}(0)$ and $H_1 = AES_{K_1}(0)$

Then, the tag for the message with $K_0$ can be expressed as:

$$C_0 + M_i H_0^i$$

where $C_0$ is a function of $K_0$, the nonce and the selected message, AAD blocks, and $M_i$ is the value we'll place into ciphertext block $i$.  One easy way to compute it is to insert a 0 where $M_i$ would go, and compute the tag as normal.

Similarly, the tag for the message with $K_1$ is:

$$C_1 + M_i H_1^i$$

So, to find $M_i$ so that they have the same tag, we equate the two, resulting in:

$$M_i = (H_0^i + H_1^i)^{-1}(C_0 + C_1)$$

(Remember, we're in $GF(2^{128})$; addition and subtraction are the same operation, so we usually express it as addition; in a different field, this would be written as $(H_0^i - H_1^i)^{-1}(C_0 - C_1)$)

Put that into the ciphertext, include the appropriate tag (computable by the above formula), and there you go.

This approach can be extended to finding a message that'll decrypt with $k$ different keys (by using $k-1$ free blocks).

> Can that extend to the point that this nightmare of the same encrypted and authenticated ciphertext decrypting to two meaningful but wildly different documents holds (for some standard document/archive format)?

Not quite; the attacker can pick the ciphertext so that it'll decrypt under one of the keys to a chosen message (except for that one block); however that gives him no control over the other decryption.

By making a reasonable assumption on AES, it would appear provable that the attacker cannot do significantly better (at least for 96 bit nonces).  GCM translates ciphertext to plaintext (assuming a valid decryption) by the operation $P_i = C_i \oplus AES_k( N(i) )$, where $N(i)$ is the nonce and the block index combined).  Hence, the xor of the two decrypted plaintexts will be, for that block $AES_{k_0}( N(i) ) \oplus AES_{k_1}( N(i))$, and that wouldn't be controllable.

Nonce sizes other than 96 bits would be harder to analyze (as $N(i)$ now becomes a function of the key); however there wouldn't be an obvious approach to break that either.

Comment: Thanks! I (now) read there has been some creative work towards partly chosen dual plaintexts so that both are meaningful. E.g. [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/016.pdf#page=10) (with [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3M1jIO-jLHI&t=733s)). Basically there are tiny segments of plaintext that are chosen for both plaintexts, using brute force; and large portions chosen for one plaintext or the other; and the semantic of file formats makes both plaintexts nearly as good as chosen (here one if a JPEG, the other a BMP, and both are valid for some software).